# How do I estimate the error while using pykalman for Kalman regression?

Tags: python, regression, kalman-filter

I'm using pykalman for regression, but I would like to estimate the error of the regression coefficient. Specifiacally, we have the following expressions:

Y(t) = B(t)X(t) + v

where the regression coefficient (B) itself is a random process given by:

B(t) = B(t-1) + w

So the "noise" I'm dealing with is given by v and w, representing gaussian noise where:

w ~ N(0, **Q**)

v ~ N(0, **R**)

Now - I would like detrmine the signal/noise ratio expressed as **Q / R**. My question is how to extract these values from the pykalman process. Currently, my code only returns the regression coefficient, but how to I get hold of Q and R?

```
 def UpdateKalman(self, ins1, ins2):
        obs_mat = np.array([[ins1, 1.0]])
        means, covs = self.kf.filter_update(self.previous_state_means.T,
                                            self.previous_state_covs[0],
                                            observation=np.asarray(ins2),
                                            observation_matrix=obs_mat)

        self.previous_state_covs = covs
        self.previous_state_means = means
        beta = means[:, 0][0]
        return beta
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the observation co-variance (which I understand you have termed R in your question), and the transition co-variance (which I understand you have termed Q), you can get them directly from the `pykalman.standard.KalmanFilter` class object.

Assuming in your example `self.kf` is suck an object you can get these as:

```
   R = self.kf.observation_covariance
   Q = self.kf.transition_covariance
```

It's my understanding that this object, and these matrices are updated in your code by the `filter_update` step even through it is not returned as an output from that function.